# Is it possible for laravel to reach 1000 TPS?

Tags: php, laravel, performance, docker, load

There is an application built on Laravel and the application should be ready for a load of 1000 requests per second.

I have done the below tasks:

1- Composer autoload has been dumped
2- Query results are cached
3- All views have been minified

What else should I consider ?

(App runs on docker container)

Comment: by transactions do you mean database transactions or requests?
In general PHP runs on its own process and to my knowledge is therefore limited by the underlying system and the amount of concurrent requests it can handle.

Comment: This is more about architecture than a particular programming issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you measuring if you reach the TPS? I would first get a baseline in order to know if your far of and based on that start looking into which part of your application stack (this includes the web and database server and other services used.) Tools that are available to use are JMeter or Apache Bench

In order to reach the 1000 TPS you'll need to tweak the webserver to allows for this type of loads. How to approach this is dependent on the webserver used. So it is difficult to provide you with specifics.

With regards to your DB server there are tools available to benchmark them as well such as pgBadger(postgres) or log files specific for the slow queries.

Ultimately you would also like to be on one of the latests PHP version as they are quite some performance gains in every new version. Currently the latest released PHP version is 7.4

In my opinion these tweaks would have a greater performance gain then tweaking the PHP code (assuming there is no mis-use of php). But this of course depends on the specifics of you application.

Optionally you should also be able to scale vertically (oppose of horizontally) to increase the TPS every time with the number of TPS per application server.

Comment: Thanks for your note, I am using NGINX as my web server and database is MySQL

Answer (score 1):

**Tips to Improve Laravel Performance**

Config caching,

Routes caching.

Remove Unused Service.

Classmap optimization.

Optimizing the composer autoload.

Limit Use Of Plugins.

Here is full detailed article [click](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/laravel-performance-optimization/amp/)